# How to prevent ClassLoader leaks when using ClassValue?

Tags: java, groovy, memory-leaks, classloader, rest-assured

For my tests, I'm using rest-assured which is partially written in Groovy.
In my application, I use a custom `ClassLoader` to load rest-assured and Groovy classes, after each test, the `ClassLoader` is closed and ready to be collected by the GC.

In case, I launch my test with `-Dgroovy.use.classvalue=false`, the class `GroovyClassValuePreJava7` is used which is the Groovy implementation of `ClassValue`, the `ClassLoader`s are properly removed from the heap but when I launch my test with `-Dgroovy.use.classvalue=true`, the class `GroovyClassValueJava7` is used which is a subtype of `ClassValue`, I end up with an OOME.

I can see thanks to my profiler that each `ClassLoader` is actually retained by a JNI Global Reference to each primitive class (`void.class`, `float.class`, `boolean.class`, `int.class`, `double.class`, `long.class`, `char.class`, `byte.class`).

[image: JNI Global References]

If I naively call `InvokerHelper.removeClass(Class)` on each of these classes, to clear the `ClassValueMap`, my `ClassLoaders` don't have any GC root anymore but unfortunately, they are still in the heap.

My test class is the following:

```
class ClassLoaderLeakTest {

    ...

    private CustomClassLoader cl;

    @BeforeEach
    void configure() {
        cl = new CustomClassLoader();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void clean() throws Exception {
        cl.close();
        cl = null;
    }

    @RepeatedTest(100)
    void test() throws Exception {
        cl.loadClass("org.example.Main").getMethod("callTest").invoke(null);
    }
}
```

The `Main` class is a simple rest-assured test:

```
public class Main {
    public static void callTest() {
        RestAssured.given()
                .when().get("/hello")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body(is("hello"));
    }
}
```

The class `CustomClassLoader` is basically an `URLClassLoader` that loads jar files from a specific lib folder:

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    public CustomClassLoader() {
        super(urls(), null);
    }

    private static URL[] urls() {
        Function<URI, URL> toURL = uri -> {
            try {
                return uri.toURL();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
        List<URL> l = Arrays.stream(
            Objects.requireNonNull(new File("./lib").listFiles())
        )
                .map(File::getAbsoluteFile)
                .map(File::toURI)
                .map(toURL).collect(Collectors.toList());
        l.add(
            toURL.apply(new File("./target/classes").getAbsoluteFile().toURI())
        );
        return l.toArray(URL[]::new);
    }
}
```

I created [a small project](https://github.com/essobedo/testCLLeak) to reproduce, any idea/help is more than welcome.

What could be the root cause of this `ClassLoader` leak?

I also tried to remove the soft, weak, and phantom references to the `ClassLoader`s but it did not change anything, I still have the `ClassLoader`s in the heap even without a path to GC roots whatever the type of reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the leak, we need to remove the associated value for all existing instances of `ClassValue` by calling `ClassValue#remove(Class)`.

In `Groovy`, the easiest way I found is by getting all the `ClassInfo` and calling `InvokerHelper.removeClass(Class)` on each underlying class when closing the `ClassLoader` as next:

```
for (ClassInfo ci : ClassInfo.getAllClassInfo()) {
    InvokerHelper.removeClass(ci.getTheClass());
}
```